# What is git's relationship to repo?

Tags: android, git, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to do some contributing to Cyanogenmod. As per the directions at https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_vendor_cm, I do the following:

```
repo init -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-11.0
repo sync
```

And, as expected, after a few hours I have the CM source! However, the documentation at http://source.android.com/source/developing.html is a little confusing.

> ### Basic Workflow
>
> The basic pattern of interacting with the repositories is as follows:
>
> Use repo start to start a new topic branch.
>
> Edit the files.
>
> Use `git add` to stage changes.
>
> Use `git commit` to commit changes.
>
> Use `repo upload` to upload changes to the review server.

Since the documentation states "Repo is a repository management tool that we built on top of Git." I assumed that once I initialized an android repo (and the fact that the URL ended in `.git`) the repo automatically would contain such an environment that I could use `git`. When I tried to follow the **Basic Workflow** instructions, however, git complained that it didn't find a git repository. This makes sense because I only saw a `.repo` directory, and no `.git` directory, like git expects.

So, then, do I need to initialize my own git repository? The instructions aren't very clear on that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to gain git functionality you must initialize it as a git repository.
Try moving to the directory you cloned and type  `git init`.

Comment: That's what I thought. I wasn't sure, though, because Google's docs on repo hint that repo *is* git, or that it accepts git commands...at least, the way *I* was reading it.